# Hide PIN text field numbers - IONIC 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an app in which I have a PIN, the HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="contain-pin">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="2"></ion-col>

      <ion-col size="2" style="padding: 2px">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="field-style">
          <input
            id="inpNro1"
            matInput
            class="pin-style"
            form="pin"
            maxlength="1"
            inputmode="numeric"
            type="password"
            pattern="[0-9]*"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col size="2" style="padding: 2px">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="field-style">
          <input
            id="inpNro2"
            matInput
            class="pin-style"
            form="pin"
            maxlength="1"
            inputmode="numeric"
            type="password"
            pattern="[0-9]*"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col size="2" style="padding: 2px">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="field-style">
          <input
            id="inpNro3"
            matInput
            class="pin-style"
            form="pin"
            maxlength="1"
            inputmode="numeric"
            type="password"
            pattern="[0-9]*"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col size="2" style="padding: 2px">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w100">
          <input
            id="inpNro4"
            matInput
            class="pin-style"
            form="pin"
            maxlength="1"
            inputmode="numeric"
            type="password"
            pattern="[0-9]*"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col size="2"></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
 </div>
```

In the app it looks like this: [image: APP]

What I need is that the numbers cannot be seen even for a single second, I would like it not to automatically see the number that the user is typing.

Is it possible to do this?

IONIC 5, ANGULAR 10

Comment: curious how it shows data in-spite with input `type="password"`.

Comment: Yes, this behavior is a bit strange. It only happens on cell phones.

Answer (score 0):

Some OSes (e.g. Android) display the last typed character for a couple of seconds.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password):

> [...] mobile devices, for example, often display the typed character for a moment before obscuring it, to allow the user to be sure they pressed the key they meant to press; this is helpful given the small size of keys and the ease with which the wrong one can be pressed, especially on virtual keyboards.

I don't think this can be disabled by the website/app so you'll have to do some manual work:

1. hide the password input (e.g. `visibility: hidden`) so it is still selectable by the user
2. on each keypress inside the input add the same number of asterisks (or any other symbol) to an element that is displayed behind the invisible password input

It makes sense to create a new component for this to keep repetition to a minimum.

Or you could use an existing component. A quick google for `angular pin input` came up with [Angular Code Input](https://github.com/AlexMiniApps/angular-code-input).